# How should I persist application static collections like a hash map of logged in users?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hashmap, persistence

I'm building an app that requires me to maintain a list of logged in users and the roles they are registered as so other users can access some logic from this list. I am using a HashMap relating User to their UserRole called LoggedInUsers for this list that is created in my Application class.

I am using PostgresSQL with Java, but don't know how to store this type of static data. Should i create another table for logged in users?

I thought of adding an isLoggedIn boolean to my User model, but i need the hash map because it allows me to get the instance (userrole) the user is logged in as, which is crucial to my business use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisiting in case anyone is wondering what the solution is:

- I found the best way to resolve this is by hosting a logged in users map serialized on a cloud service. The application will then have a scheduled task (every 5 seconds or so) to merge the local logged in users map with the cloud map, providing constant time access to logged in users and across multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another table.
But I think it would be better to use Redis for that.
It is an inmemory database. And mostly used for this type of tasks.

Comment: the other use case for this is to allow access to this data across different instances. in memory db will not allow this.